# How do i using DeveExpress XtraGrid? Giving 'Columns' is not a member error

Tags: .net, winforms, datagrid, devexpress, xtragrid

I am new to DevExpress, I change my old DataGridView control for DevExpress GridControl.
But my old codes gives error:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(12).Visible
DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height
DataGridView1.Rows.Count

'Columns' is not a member of 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl'
'RowTemplate' is not a member of 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl'
'Rows' is not a member of 'DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl'
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, start from reading the [XtraGrid documentation](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3455). Then use the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Anyway, here are some answers:

XtraGrid does not actually display data by itself. It uses [**Views**](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3462) to represent data.
You can refer the View itself or refer to the GridControl's main View using the [GridControl.MainView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_MainViewtopic) property.

> DataGridView1.Columns(12).Visible

All columns are stored in the [ColumnView.Columns](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_Columnstopic) collection. Use the [GridColumn.Visible](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_Visibletopic) property to specify the column's visibility.

> DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height

You can set data row height manually using the View's [GridView.RowHeight](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowHeighttopic) property

> DataGridView1.Rows.Count

Use the [GridView.RowCount](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_RowCounttopic) property.

Comment: [Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387)